# How to have Spring @DataJpaTest annotation on subclass instead of having it be required on the abstract superclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to create an abstract test class for my (Spring) repositories, to be implemented twice: once using the actual JPA repository, once using an in memory fake. (See https://wiki.c2.com/?AbstractTestCases)

For this I have the following setup:

An abstract superclass, which requires the `@DataJpaTest` annotation

```java
@DataJpaTest
public abstract class RepositoryTest {
    abstract TestRepo repo();
    abstract void save(Entity entity);

    @Test
    void testtest() {
       save(new Entity("ProviderId", new Date(), "event", "phase", "cat", "batch", "me" +
                "message"));

       assertThat(repo().findAll()).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

and a concrete subclass, which requires some other Spring annotations:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestRepo.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class JpaRepositoryTest extends RepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager em;

    @Override
    void save(Entity entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    TestRepo repo() {
        return jpaTestRepo;
    }

}
```

(The in-memory test is trivial, the save method just saves to the fake repo's in-memory map directly)

Because I'm structuring my code as a ports & adapters architecture, and using Gradle modules to enforce the boundaries between the ports & adapters, the `RepositoryTest` and the `JpaRepositoryTest` are in different modules. The former is in the domain module, which should not depend on any framework such as Spring.

I am however forced to add the `@DataJpaTest` on the abstract superclass (in the domain module) or otherwise I get the (confusing error):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager found, is your test running in a transaction?

Is there any way to setup the `JpaRepositoryTest` to have all the Spring annotations, and keep the `RepositoryTest itself free from Spring?

Answer (score 1):

> I am however forced to add the @DataJpaTest on the abstract superclass (in the domain module) or otherwise I get the (confusing error)

You face the exception because you cannot use `TestEntityManager` without `@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager`, which is in turn a member of `@DataJpaTest` (see [the fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/28086) for [the issue 28067](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28067)):

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@BootstrapWith(DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(
  enabled = false
)
@TypeExcludeFilters({DataJpaTypeExcludeFilter.class})
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureCache
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager // <----
@ImportAutoConfiguration
public @interface DataJpaTest {}
```

If your intention is to use both in-memory and real JPA repos you could use adapter bearing `@DataJpaTest` and plain abstract class:

```java
public abstract class RepositoryTest {
    abstract TestRepo repo();
    abstract void save(Entity entity);

    @Test
    void testtest() {
       save(new Entity("ProviderId", new Date(), "event", "phase", "cat", "batch", "me" +
                "message"));

       assertThat(repo().findAll()).isNotNull();
    }
}


@DataJpaTest
public abstract class InMemoryRepositoryTestAdapter extends RepositoryTest {
}
```

The test classes dedicated for fake repos are then sub-classed from `InMemoryRepositoryTestAdapter` and the ones dealing with "real" JPA are inherited from `RepositoryTest`.

Pay attention, that you cannot use `TestEntityManager` with "real" JPA repositories and I'd use the repos themselves for test set-up.

Comment: I don't see how moving the DataJPA to an intermediate abstract class solves the problem. I tried it now and the issue persists: Spring requires the @DataJpaTest annotation to be on the class containing the tests themselves.